# Weird backticks behaviour in Active Record in CodeIgniter 2.0.3

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, select, backticks

Previously my all queries were running fine in CI version 2.0 but when I upgraded to **2.0.3** some of my SELECT queries were broken.

CI is adding **backticks (``)** automatically, but in older version its running as it is.

CI user manual have instructed to add second parameter in

> db->select

as

> FALSE

but still it's not working.

Code is as following:

```
class Company_model extends MY_Model
{

----------------

$this->db->select(' count('.$fieldname. ') as num_stations');
$this->db->select(" CONCAT_WS(',', clb_company.address1, clb_company.address2, clb_company.city, clb_company.state, clb_company.zipcode ) as companyAddress");
$this->db->from($this->_table);
$this->db->join($this->_table_device, $fieldname1. " = ".  $fieldname2, 'LEFT');
$this->db->where($blablafield , '0');
----------------
```

The error is as follows:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM (`clb_device`) JOIN `clb_company` ON `clb_company`.`id` = `clb_device`.`com' at line 2

SELECT `clb_device`.`id` as deviceId, `clb_pricing_specifications`.`name` as pricingSpecName, `clb_company`.`name` as companyName, `clb_device`.`mac_address` as deviceMacAddress, 
`clb_device`.`reseller_model_number` as deviceModelNumber, `clb_pricing_spec_grouping`.`pricing_master_spec_id` as pricingSpecId, `clb_device`.`address` as deviceAddress, 
`clb_device`.`is_home` as deviceIsHomeCharger, CONCAT(clb_company.portal_line1, `'/'`, `clb_device`.`name)` as deviceDisplayName FROM (`clb_device`) JOIN `clb_company` 
ON `clb_company`.`id` = `clb_device`.`company_id` LEFT JOIN `clb_pricing_group_devices` ON `clb_device`.`id` = `clb_pricing_group_devices`.`device_id` and clb_pricing_group_devices.is_active = 1 
LEFT JOIN `clb_pricing_spec_grouping` ON `clb_pricing_group_devices`.`pricing_spec_id` = `clb_pricing_spec_grouping`.`pricing_master_spec_id` LEFT JOIN `clb_pricing_specifications` ON 
`clb_pricing_spec_grouping`.`pricing_spec_id` = `clb_pricing_specifications`.`id` WHERE clb_company.vendor_id is not null AND cast(substr(clb_devi
ce.software_version, 1, 3) as decimal(2,1)) > 2.0 AND clb_device.device_state > 0 GROUP BY `clb_device`.`id` ORDER BY CONCAT(trim(clb_company.portal_line1), `'/'`, trim(clb_device.name)) desc LIMIT 20
```

Have a look at **CONCAT(trim(clb_company.portal_line1), `'/'`, trim(clb_device.name))**

Please suggest the workaround.

Comment: I would have thought the backticks would make no real difference to the query as they'll just encapsulate the table/field names in your query to allow for special characters if you use `echo $this->db->last_query();` and post the code that might allow us to shed more light on it.

Comment: @simnom - it is creating problem, e.g. CONCAT(trim(table1.field1), '/', trim(table2.field2)) is being parsed as CONCAT(trim(table1.field1), `'/'`, trim(table2.field2))

Comment: Please include your Active record code in the question.

Comment: @Louis --- have included the code sample in question itself, sorry for the delays

Answer (score 32):

Use this line before your query:

```php
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

This will stop adding backticks to the built query.

Answer (score 15):

The solution is very simple: 
In the database configuration file (./application/config/database.php) add a new element to array with default settings.

```
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;
```

This solution is working for me and more elegant and professional.

Comment: This has any impact on security  ?

Answer (score 7):

All other answers are really old, this one works with CI 2.1.4

```
// set this to false so that _protect_identifiers skips escaping:
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;

// your order_by line:
$this -> db -> order_by('FIELD ( products.country_id, 2, 0, 1 )');

// important to set this back to TRUE or ALL of your queries from now on will be non-escaped:
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Company_model extends MY_Model
{

----------------

$this->db->select(" count('$fieldname') as num_stations",false);
$this->db->select(" CONCAT_WS(',', clb_company.address1, clb_company.address2, clb_company.city, clb_company.state, clb_company.zipcode ) as companyAddress",false);
$this->db->from($this->_table);
$this->db->join($this->_table_device, $fieldname1. " = ".  $fieldname2, 'LEFT');
$this->db->where($blablafield , '0');
----------------
```

The `false` you were talking about is what is needed, can you try the code above and copy and paste to us the output of

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

This will show us what the DB class is creating exactly and we can see whats working / what isn't. It may be something else (you haven't given the error from that is generated sometimes sql errors can be misleading.)

From the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select):

`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: Louis, I have included the query and error,Please have a look.

Comment: This might be a long shot but have you put the false param on the company info but not on the query that gives the error? (as in do you use concat more than one in this file? - the sample code and error don't match, may just be you using sample code or may not be I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 2):

CI will only protect your ACTIVE RECORD calls, so if you are running `$this->db->query();` you will be fine, and based on the notes you should be safe with AD calls like so to disable backticks (not sure why you say they don't work, but I don't see your full code, so I can't be sure)

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

make sure `FALSE` is without single quotes (makes it a string), and it might not validate (not tested by me).

Comment: Thanks for he explanation Jakub, real problem occurs when you use some built in functions with comma as separators like I gave the example of CONCAT(field1, '-', field2) and you come up with concat(`field1`, `'-'`, `field2`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check DB_driver.php file, there is a variable named as protect_identifier, the point is when you will check with older version of CI, you will see that there is a condition which is missing in new version,escape variable which is checked for nullability, paste that condition from older version and you will be OK

Answer (score 1):

`CI_DB_active_record::where()`  has a third param for escaping, this has worked better for me than switching on and off `CI_DB_driver::_protect_identifiers`

```
public function where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE)
```

Not sure what CI version this was added in.

HTH someone

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that worked for me. Replace this line

```
$this->db->join($this->_table_device, $fieldname1. " = ".  $fieldname2, 'LEFT');
```

with this:

```
$this->db->join($this->_table_device, $fieldname1. " IN(".  $fieldname2 .")", 'LEFT');
```

this will prevent CI from escaping your field. It's not ideal but it's better than the alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

I just read a simple solution for this...

I changed  the value of var $_escape_char (system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php, line 36..

It was

```
var $_escape_char = '`';
```

Changed to

```
var $_escape_char = ' ';
```

and now it works... But i am affraid if I made any security issues..

Thanks

Comment: Definitely Roopa, you have opened the door for INJECTIONS, it is not recommended, revert the code to original.