# Is this a bug in Codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

If I used codeigniter active record to fetch data from a db table like this:

```
$where = array("first_name" => "John", "age <" => 30, "status" => "active");
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get("my_table");

die(var_dump($this->db->last_query())); // displays the query string
```

This code will produce the following query string:

```
SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE `first_name` = 'John' AND `age` < 30 AND `status` = 'active'
```

Now if I assigned a string to `$where` instead of the array, like this:

```
$where = "first_name = 'John' AND age < 30 AND status = 'active'";
```

Then it will produce the following query string:

```
SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE `first_name` = 'John' AND age < 30 AND status = 'active'
```

Notice that when assign a string to `$where`, codeigniter added [``` backticks (``) ```](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) only around the first field's name which is `first_name` in our case. While on the other hand, codeigniter added backticks around all fields names when we assigned an array to `$where`

My question: Is this a bug in codeigniter or this is normal? And if I used the following code to prevent codeigniter from adding backticks around fields names:

```
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

Which will produce the following query string:

```
SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE first_name = 'John' AND age < 30 AND status = 'active'
```

Is there any risks or cons of writing `where` portion this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is this a bug in codeigniter or this is normal?

- Yes its a bug, but not a serious one.

Q: Is there any risks or cons of writing $this->db->where($where, null, false)?

This code is not risky by itself. and if you are hard coding in your WHERE clause then there would likely never be an issue. The only time an issue would arise is when you would capturing user input, for example a form, or a URL, and this would be something you would have to sanitize manually

**its going to be very important that you sanitize your where clause.**

**BAD Example: Vunerable to SQL Injection**

```
$fname  = $_POST['fname']; 
$age    = $_POST['age'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

$where  = sprintf("first_name = '%s' AND age < %d AND status = '%s'",$fname,$age,$status);
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

**BETTER Example: less vunerable**

```
$fname  = (string) mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$age    = (int) $_POST['age'];
$status = (string) mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);

$where  = sprintf("first_name = '%s' AND age < %d AND status = '%s'",$fname,$age,$status);
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

Nothing your doing so far is wrong, it will just put more of the burden to sanitize your where clauses on you, being that using $this->db->where($where, null, false) will remove built in sanitation.

**In Short**: using this method, makes you more vulnerable initially to SQL injection if you where clauses will have user input provided. But nothing you cant tighten up quickly with a few sanitation functions.

i know this answer inst perfect, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

This is the risky way as CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

For missing backticks, It seems bug as some of the Stack overflow user also mention problem in query while generating with group_concat option. This is one of the example.

[Weird backticks behaviour in Active Record in Code Igniter 2.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7482594/270037)

Answer (score 0):

No, this shouldn't be an issue at least in this case. The backticks allow alternative characters in the field names. As neither age nor status contain any characters which may cause an issue, the backticks are unnecessary. Also, the usage of backticks varies depending on the SQL server used.

See this question for reference: [Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names)

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter active record you must be define column name by one quote (if your string is in double quote). to see this feature clearly. see `where` code in system folder.